# How to prove that the limit doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits

I suspect that the limit of the following sequence doesn't exist as $n$ approaches infinity.

$$x_n= n^{(1/2-\sin n)}$$

Wolfram alpha [is unable to](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20n%20tends%20to%20infinity%20n%5E%281%2F2%20-%20sin%20n%29%20) compute this limit. However, I it seems intuitive by looking at its [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20n%5E%281%2F2%20-%20sin%20n%29%20from%20n%3D1%20to%20n%3D1000%20).

How can I prove this result?

Comment: Hint: prove that the exponent is greater than $1/4$ infinitely many times.

Comment: For what $n$ is $x_n$ really large? For what $n$ is $x_n$ really small? You seem to be closer to the answer than you think

Comment: @Wojowu That can be divergence as well.

Comment: @Curious For me, a sequence which diverges doesn't have a limit either, but I understand if you mean otherwise.

Comment: I got the answer btw. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist because $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} x_n=0 \neq +\infty= \limsup_{n\to \infty} x_n$$ To see this you need to take a subsequence $n_k$ with $\sin n_k<1/2$ for all $n_k \in \mathbb N$ and another $n_m$ with $\sin n_m>1/2$ for all $n_m \in \mathbb N$. (Due to periodicity of $\sin$ there are infinitely many of both, so you can find such sub-sequences).

Comment: Would the sequence $n_k, n_m$, such that $\sin n_k=0$ and $\ sin  {n_m}=1/2$ work?

Comment: @Curious That would work if  $\sin n_k=0$ for $n_k \in \mathbb N$ but I do not think that this is the case (I am terrible with calculations with $\sin$).

Comment: It takes a tad more than periodicity of sin to prove there are subsequences with sine values on each side of $1/2$.  Also, to be safe, you should probably take subsequences with $\sin n_k$ bounded *away* from $1/2$ on each side (see the remark about "Goldilocks" integers in my answer).

Comment: I later came to realize that the periodicity doesn't help when the domain is integers for sin.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, but periodicity can simplify things. It suffices to find only one $n$ such that $\sin n>1/2$ and one $m$ such that $\sin m<1/2$, then this already shows that there infinitely many of both. For example $\sin 1>1/2$ and $\sin 3<1/2$ so, this settles it. Except my logic is wrong.

Comment: @JimmyR. How does the periodicity help? sin 1>1/2 but then 1+2pi is not an integer.

Comment: @Curious. You know that $\sin$ has a period of $2\pi\approx 6.28$. In The interval $[0, 6.28]$ there are integers, for example $n=1$, such that $\sin 1>1/2$ and integers, for example $m=3$, such that $\sin m<1/2$. Now, in the interval $[6.28, 2\times 6.28]$ (approximately) the $\sin$ takes the same values as in the interval $[0, 6.28]$ and so on. So, the value $\sin n >1/2$ is repeated infinitely many times and so is the value $\sin m<1/2$. Do you find this convincing?

Answer (score 1):

The values of $\sin n$ are the values of the $y$ coordinates of the points on the unit circle that you land on when marching counterclockwise starting from $(1,0)$ in steps of arc length $1$.  Now since the arcs

$$(2k\pi+{\pi\over2}-{\pi\over6},2k\pi+{\pi\over2}+{\pi\over6})\quad\text{and}\quad(2k\pi-{\pi\over2}-{\pi\over6},2k\pi-{\pi\over2}+{\pi\over6})$$

are all of arc length ${\pi/3}\gt1$, the march will land in each of them.

For the first batch, $\sin n\gt\sin{\pi\over3}={\sqrt3\over2}\gt{1\over2}$, and for the second, $\sin n\lt-\sin{\pi\over3}\lt-{\sqrt3\over2}\lt-{1\over2}$.  Thus infinitely often the sequence $n^{(1/2-\sin n)}$ takes values less than $n^{(1-\sqrt3)/2}$, which is less than $1$ for $n\ge2$, and infinitely often it takes values greater than $n^{(1+\sqrt3)/2}$, which is greater than $2$ for $n\ge2$.  Hence the sequence does not have a limit as $n\to\infty$.

Remark:  It's not hard to show that the aforementioned subsequences tend, in fact, to $0$ and $\infty$.  It might be of interest to ask if there are subsequences that tend to anything in between -- i.e., are there "Goldilocks" integers $n$ that that $\sin n$ is close enough to $1/2$ to make $n^{(1/2-\sin n)}$ neither too big nor too small?

Comment: Can this result be used to establish that $n^{c-\sin n}$ doesn't have a limit as $n$ approaches infinity? where c is a positive real number?

Comment: @Curious, if $c\gt1$, then $n^{c-\sin n}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.  If $0\lt c\lt1$, there are certainly subsequences that tend to $\infty$, but you need to use the irrationality of $\pi$ to show that there are subsequences tending to $0$.  (Note, my answer, for $c=1/2$, doesn't need the irrationality of $\pi$, only that $\pi\gt3$.)  For $c=1$, my "Goldilocks" comment applies:  It's unclear (to me) if $n^{1-\sin n}$ has any subsequences converging to anything other than $\infty$.